# Texas Accelerated Rent

Tags: united-states, real-estate-leasing

I have to pay $7,022 in accelerated rent charges. Due in 30 days, does anyone have any experience with this? I asked the apartment for a payment plan and haven't heard back. What are ways I can save my credit.

Comment: Try to find the management company a tenant to take over your lease ASAP, and that they agree that that mitigates the issue.

Comment: According to http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=04d237c9-5937-4d23-ae5f-74ce94910e2c "An acceleration of rent provision gives the landlord the right, **after a default by the tenant**, to demand the entire balance of the unpaid rent" Of course they won't give you a payment plan, because they don't think you'll honor it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your best bet will be to either discuss your options directly with your landlord / leasing office / property management office (Whichever applies here), or to discuss your options with a lawyer.

The leasing office / property manager / landlord may be willing to work with you on this, but **usually clauses like this only apply if you've gone into default** - Find and read your lease to see the specifics in your agreement, including any limitations or remedies available.

If there's **absolutely** nothing you can do to avoid the accelerated payments, and you simply want to know the answer to **"What can I do to avoid damaging my credit?"** , the answer is going to be fairly straight-forward: **Pay the bill.**

If you owe this money, the best option to avoid it being reported as a missed payment or defaulted balance (Disregarding any un-stated circumstances such as an existing default that led to this scenario) is going to be to pay the balance in full.

**If you don't have this amount in cash**, you may need to take out some sort of loan to pay it off.

I'm not recommending you do this, but I'm saying it's something you can attempt to do to pay off this balance you owe to the landlord before they report it as a **missed payment.**

Of course if you did that, you'd end up paying interest on a loan; **You'll need to decide for yourself what's more important to you in this scenario.**

To summarize, definitely try to work things out directly with your landlord / leasing office. **Read your lease, in its entirety, to understand the obligations you've agreed to.**

If all else fails, investigate what options are available to you to get the balance paid in full A.S.A.P, to meet your stated goal of protecting your credit.